# ID in the QueryString not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer

SP 2013, SP Designer 2013

I have a form which lists different records... when the user clicks one of these records it takes them to a Custom Display form, using a QueryString "ID"

My issue is the form isn't displaying the correct record, and I have found other instance where people report the same issue when the key record is named "ID"

Is there a way to use a ID field and if so, how to I alter the recordset on the displayform to query by the new ID form?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ID correctly in the url string...

`https://yoursite/list/forms/myCustomForm.aspx?id={yourID}`

this should pull the infomation into your custom form based on the id.

Comment: I have narrowed my issue down to the following problem, but, not sure how to update the Parameter in SharePoint 2013:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972225/no-item-exists-at-http-server-site-mypage-aspx-id-1--it-may-have-been

Comment: SO, I have went through SharePoint designer, and tried to update the Paramter, and then the datasource to match, BUT, I keep getting errors. 

Steps: Edit Parameter by changing the "Query String Variable" to something other than "ID"  In this instance I changed it to "EventID"

I then went into the datasource and clicked on "Filter" and then changed the Field Name from "Content Type to "ID" and then "Value" to "ListItemID" which is the name of the parameter... BUT, I am now getting the following error:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
Correlation ID:947e239e-5414-f04e-e83c-075ada3d22a9